# Why does my submit button not work in my Django form template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have posted a couple questions about this the past two days and haven't really gotten any answers.  Basically what I'm trying to do is merge my own template with this Userena template.  The reason being that I want to apply CSS styling and the only way I know how to do that is with the code under My Custom Sign Up Template.  Since the last time I posted this question I have made some progress in that I have added the correct ID's into my custom form.

Nothing happens when I hit the submit button though, I'm wondering if I just made a basic error with my submit button?  Or if I'm just completely headed down the wrong path here and what I'm trying to do is not possible.

There are other problems with my custom example, for instance, I see the password in the url string when I hit submit, but for right now my question is mainly just why does my submit button not submit anything?

## Userena Sign Up Template

```
{% block title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <legend>{% trans "Signup" %}</legend>
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% for field in form %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {% comment %} Displaying checkboxes differently {% endcomment %}
    {% if field.name == 'tos' %}
    <p class="checkbox">
    <label for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field }} {{ field.label }}</label>
    </p>
    {% else %}
    <p>
    {{ field.label_tag }} 
    {{ field }}
    </p>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Sign Up"%}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

## My Custom Sign Up Template

```
<body>
  <form class="sign-up">
    <h1 class="sign-up-title">Get Started</h1>
    <input type="text" class="sign-up-input" placeholder="Name" autofocus="" id="id_username" name=username >
    <input type="text" class="sign-up-input" placeholder="Email" id="id_email" name="email">
    <input type="password" class="sign-up-input" placeholder="Password" id="id_password1" name="password1">
    <input type="password" class="sign-up-input" placeholder="Repeat" id="id_password2" name="password2">
    <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="sign-up-button">
  </form>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You do not have define any action.kindly define an action page where your form will submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your submit doesn't work because your form doesn't have the "action=''" attr

```
<form class='sign-up' action='/accounts/signup/' method='post'>
```

and add the

`{% csrf_token %}`

Good Luck